# Launch Activity onCreate() called 2 times when the app installed and launch first time in android 12 and above

Tags: android, kotlin, android-splashscreen

Launch Activity onCreate() was called 2 times when the app was installed and launched the first time in Android 12 and above

Getting this kind of error while integrating splash screen API according to Google Docs.
1> Device
Android 12 and above
2> Android Studio
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
3> Kotlin
kotling_version 1.8.22
4> SDK
minSDK 25
targetSdk 34
compileSdk 34

Comment: Can you share your `onCreate` method?